# C# Selenium webdriver selectByText containing from listbox or dropdow

Tags: c#, selenium, listbox, webdriver, selenium-webdriver

I use code which perfectly selects item from listbox by visible text.

```
 var selectElement = new SelectElement(TestFramework.FindWebElement(this));
 selectElement.SelectByText(text);
```

The problem is i have dynamically changed text in items. It could be like:

-- item1 -- or 
--- item1 ---

but i need to select the item with text containing "item1". Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at the source, The `SelectByText` method should go and search for `contains` matches if the first search (a direct `Equals` match) returns nothing. In the event that it is not doing this, raise a bug with the Selenium Developer's and write your own extension method in the mean time:

```
/// <summary>
/// Select an option by first searching for a case insensitive direct match then trying a case insenstive contains match.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="selectElement">The SelectElement to use.</param>
/// <param name="searchText">The text to find in the options.</param>
public static void SelectByText(this SelectElement selectElement, string searchText)
{
    var allOptionsThatHaveText =
        selectElement.Options.Where(se => se.Text.Equals(searchText, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase));

    if (allOptionsThatHaveText.Any())
    {
        foreach (var option in allOptionsThatHaveText)
        {
            option.Click();
        }
        return;
    }

    var optionWithText = selectElement.Options.Where(option => option.Text.IndexOf(searchText, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) >= 0);
    if (optionWithText.Any())
    {
        foreach (var option in optionWithText)
        {
            option.Click();
        }
        return;
    }

    throw new NoSuchElementException(string.Format("Cannot find the text: {0} by either a case insenstive match or a case insensitive equals match.", searchText));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use XPath instead of SelectByText and within the XPath use '[contains](http://seleniumhq.org/docs/appendix_locating_techniques.html)'.

Here is an example:

```
var selectElement = new SelectElement(_driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[contains(text(), 'YOUTEXTHERE')]")));
```

Comment: could you provide an example?

Comment: thanks, but you provide code for location the listbox object. I need to locate item in this listbox by text containing.

Comment: Go to the link provided, this should give you the tools to construct an XPath for your situation. If you get stuck post back here and I should be able to look at it tomorrow.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the following code:-

```
var option = new SelectElement(browser.FindElement(By.CssSelector("#Menu_ParentMenuID"))).SelectBySubText("item1");
```